# MakeSignature.SignDeferred & Embedding Signature Problem (Itextsharp)

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, signature

I have a smart card reader. I want to sign a pdf with it. I almost succedded but i get an error when i open pdf in acrobat reader:

Signed by DENİZ KASAR

"Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed"

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rFnaYmLwTRtrPMfHO7jLKZ0-6nUvzjJI) is my certs, raw and final pdf.

**toBeSignedSTR**
BF080D04029AB900082C6DC1E1E21E947C5B61F57BD91B974138657DBA7FFDB0

**signedDataSTR**
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

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
                                    string rawPDF = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "files", "pdf_raw.pdf");
                                    string tempPDF = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "files", "pdf_temp.pdf");
                                    string finalPDF = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "files", "pdf_signed.pdf");

                                    var chain = tckk_api_basic_samples.pcsc.CertValidation.GetChain();
                                    var dotNetCert = tckk_api_basic_samples.pcsc.CertValidation.GetSigningCert();
                                    var x509cert = new myalias.Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser().ReadCertificate(dotNetCert.GetRawCertData());

    var sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", false);

    var toBeSigned = CreatePDF(rawPDF, tempPDF, chain, x509cert);// return DigestAlgorithms.Digest(sap.GetRangeStream(), "SHA256");

    var att = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(toBeSigned, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);//77bytes

    //SIGNING func
    var signedData = tckk_api_basic_samples.pcsc.Sign_Validate.Sign(att, "578310");//256bytes

    sgn.SetExternalDigest(signedData, null, "RSA");

    byte[] encodedSignature = sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7(att, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);

    EmbedSignature2(tempPDF, finalPDF, encodedSignature);

    Process.Start(finalPDF);
        }

        public static myalias::Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] GetChain()
        {
                            IServiceContainer4All serviceContainer = new TCKKServiceContainer(1);
                            X509Certificate certificate = serviceContainer.GetCertificateService().GetKimlikDogrulamaCertificate();

                            X509Chain x509chain = new X509Chain();
                            x509chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

                            X509Certificate2 rootCert = new X509Certificate2(Resources.kokshs_t2);
                            X509Certificate2 intermediateCert = new X509Certificate2(Resources.kyshs_t2);
                            X509Certificate2 clientCert = new X509Certificate2(certificate);

                            x509chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(rootCert);
                            x509chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(intermediateCert);

                            if (x509chain.Build(clientCert))
                            {
                                var chain = new List<myalias::Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate>();

                                foreach (X509ChainElement x509ChainElement in x509chain.ChainElements)
                                    chain.Add(myalias::Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(x509ChainElement.Certificate));

                                return chain.ToArray();
                            }
                            else
                                return null;
        }

        private byte[] CreatePDF(string rawPDF, string tempPDF, myalias.Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert)
        {
                                byte[] toBeSigned = null;
                                using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(rawPDF))
                                {
                                    using (FileStream signedPdf = new FileStream(tempPDF, FileMode.Create))
                                    {
                                        PdfStamper pdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfReader, signedPdf, '\0');
                                        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;
                                        sap.SetVisibleSignature(new myalias.iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(36, 748, 250, 400), 1, "SIG");
                                        sap.Reason = "MyRes";
                                        sap.Location = "MyLoc";
                                        sap.Certificate = cert;

                                        IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
                                        MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(sap, external, 8192);


                                        toBeSigned = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(sap.GetRangeStream(), "SHA256");
                                    }
                                }
                                return toBeSigned;
        }

        void EmbedSig(string tempPDF, string finalPDF, byte[] sign)
        {
                                using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(tempPDF))
                                {
                                    using (FileStream os = new FileStream(finalPDF, FileMode.Create))
                                    {
                                        IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(sign);
                                        MakeSignature.SignDeferred(reader, "SIG", os, external);
                                    }
                                }
        }

    class MyExternalSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
    {
            byte[] sig = null;
            public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] sig)
            {
                this.sig = sig;
            }

            public void ModifySigningDictionary(myalias.iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary signDic)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
            {
                return this.sig;
            }
    }
```

Comment: anybody? i am totally stuck here :((

Comment: First of all an aside, using `File.OpenWrite` is dangerous here if at the location in question there may still be some old file; if the new file is longer than the old one, no problem, but if the new one is shorter, the resulting file will have some remains from the old file after its intended end.

Answer (score 0):

#### Your original code and example signature

To start with, decrypting the signature bytes with your certificate's public key results in something that clearly is neither PKCS1-v1_5 padded nor EMSA-PSS encoded. Thus, your smart card either does not sign using the private key associated with that certificate `C=TR,SERIALNUMBER=90000000684,CN=DENİZ KASAR` or the result it returns is not the plain signature bytes array for a RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 or RSASSA-PSS signature for your input of a hash value.

Probably there are multiple private keys for different certificates on your card and you addressed the wrong one. Probably there is a different issue.

---

Furthermore, you call `getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes` with these parameters

```
byte[] signatureHash = signature.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

then store `hash` in a local variable `_hash`, but finally call `GetEncodedPKCS7` with these parameters

```
byte[] encodedSignature = _signature.GetEncodedPKCS7(_signatureHash, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

This looks incorrect, the parameters of these calls (except the TSA client) are expected to coincide, you should use `_hash` here, too.

#### Your later example signature

In a comment you confirmed that your smart card has two certificates. Apparently in you newer code you also successfully addressed the signing application for the certificate you want to sign with as the signature bytes after RSA decryption end with `0xbc` which is an indicator for RSASSA-PSS signatures.

This also has a downside, though: The iText 5.x signing API was not implemented with RSASSA-PSS in mind and in particular the `PdfPKCS7` class cannot properly build CMS containers from RSASSA-PSS signatures.

That doesn't mean, though, that you cannot use iText for signing with your card, you merely have to implement more in your own code, in particular you have to build the whole signature container.

For this you use this `MakeSignature` helper

```
/**
 * Sign the document using an external container, usually a PKCS7. The signature is fully composed
 * externally, iText will just put the container inside the document.
 * @param sap the PdfSignatureAppearance
 * @param externalSignatureContainer the interface providing the actual signing
 * @param estimatedSize the reserved size for the signature
 * @throws GeneralSecurityException
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws DocumentException 
 */
public static void SignExternalContainer(PdfSignatureAppearance sap, IExternalSignatureContainer externalSignatureContainer, int estimatedSize)
```

and merely have to implement `IExternalSignatureContainer` to build and return a CMS signature container in its `Sign` method which signs the data from the given stream.

You can build that CMS container using BouncyCastle classes or probably even Microsoft classes. Unfortunately, though, I'm mostly into this hands-on signing stuff in Java, not in .Net, so I cannot really help with that.

#### In case of RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signatures

An alternative approach would be to check whether you can tell your smart card to generate RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signatures instead as this would allow you to use iText to generate your CMS container. I wouldn't recommend this as RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 is more open to attacks than RSASSA-PSS.

In a comment, though, you specifically asked about that case. In that case I'd propose you change your signing code considerably. It currently uses a mix of the old, more low-level, and the new, more high-level, iText signing APIs. You should use the new API only.

In that case your signing code would reduce to this pivotal code

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SRC))
using (FileStream os = new FileStream(DEST, FileMode.Create))
{
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');
    // Creating the appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
    appearance.Reason = "MyRes";
    appearance.Location = "MyLoc";
    appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 250, 400), 1, "SIG");
    // Creating the signature
    CustomExternalSignature pks = new CustomExternalSignature();
    MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pks, pks.GetChain(), null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
}
```

in combination with the `CustomExternalSignature` helper class bundling your device specific code:

```
public class CustomExternalSignature : IExternalSignature
{
    public ICollection<X509Certificate> GetChain()
    {
        [essentially your GetChain method, but return the List as is, don't make it an array]]
    }

    public string GetEncryptionAlgorithm()
    {
        return "RSA";
    }

    public string GetHashAlgorithm()
    {
        return "SHA256";
    }

    public byte[] Sign(byte[] message)
    {
        [your code to call the smart card function to sign the message using RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5]
        [you might or might not have to hash the message first, I don't know that smart card API you use]
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @mkl, thank you for your attention. I have changed my code , added certs and hash strings. I am still getting "document has been altered or corrupted..." error message. Please could you take a look what going is wrong?

Comment: Actually you are right @mkl, i have two certs in my smart card. You will see in my google account the cert that i want to use. Can i use signDetached? I dont know the difference between signDetach and signDeferred.Which one is more proper for my purpose?

Comment: I'll look at the shared files when I'm back in office. Concerning your question *"Can i use signDetached? I dont know the difference between signDetach and signDeferred.Which one is more proper for my purpose?"* - you sign using some smart card. That usually means that you retrieve a signature pretty quickly after requesting it. That is a typical `signDetach` situation. `signDeferred` is for situations in which retrieval of the signature may take some time and you don't want reserve the resources for all that time. Or for other situations requiring splitting the signing process.

Comment: @DenizKasar In your edits you stopped signing the `getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes`. Thus, it cannot work at all anymore. But one positive thing, it looks like the correct certificate now is used.

Comment: I have updated my code @mkl
You can look at the "button2_Click" code part. I think i miss something again.
Also , do i need to hash after digest? What is the differences between hash and digest?

Comment: @DenizKasar I just realized one issue, your card appears to generate RSASSA-PSS signatures (in contrast to RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signatures). By itself this is **good** as the old RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 scheme is more open to attacks. Unfortunately for you, though, the iText `PdfPKCS7` class as is cannot generate proper CMS containers for RSASSA-PSS signatures, in case of RSA keys it always assumes that the RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 scheme shall be used. Thus, any solution using the `PdfPKCS7` won't work for you. But you can use the `MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer` method instead!

Comment: Alternatively (less secure) you can look for a way to ask your smart card to sign the old (RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5) way. I would not recommend that, though.

Comment: thank you for comments about RSASSA-PSS. If i understood correctly, i have to use bouncycastle to produce cms container, not PKCS7 class of  itext. So, I will study it. If you have a link about it, it would be great. I started to google. thank you so much @mkl

Comment: dear @mkl, assume that i decided to use RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5. what would you say about my code? especially "button2_Click" codes.

Comment: @DenizKasar *"assume that i decided to use RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5. what would you say about my code?"* - I'd change it considerably. See the new section "In case of RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signatures" of my answer. As I don't have your smart card API, though, the code obviously is untested and contains code placeholders for you to fill in.